# sup norm of bounded continuous functional

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

What kind of norm is (4.3)? I have searched the web and found this definition.

Let $S$ be acompact Hausdorff toplogical space. The $C(S)$ of continuous functios $x$ on $S$ with supremum norm
$$
||x||=\sup_{p\in S}|x(p)|
$$
Is this the same norm used in the passage?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, $A$ is a dual vector so we think of it as an operator and we can use the standard operator norm which is what (4.3) is.  This really is different from the sup norm in that one is defined on vector and the other dual vectors.